# Thread pitch of Ender 3 bed leveling screws

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling

What is the thread pitch of the Ender 3's bed leveling screws? The diameter measures about 4mm. Are they M4 0.7 (coarse) pitch or 0.5 (fine) pitch? I'd like to develop rigorous formulas for the amount to turn the knobs by after measuring (or visually inspecting, since I can see an accurate 0.2 mm first layer decently well) leveling-test patterns in the corners rather than using a closed-loop tune-and-retry approach.

Comment: Ideas for measuring this are nice, but I wonder if there's a spec on it available somewhere..

Comment: Incidentally, it's easier to see the arrows on the knobs if you fill them in with paint, e.g. use a white paint pen and wipe off any excess immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I measured mine with a thread gauge and it says the pitch is **0.7 mm**.

So, as the stock adjustment wheels have 14 bumps around their circumference, turning by one of those is an adjustment of exactly 0.05 mm (assuming no backlash).

I can't speak for anyone else's, but due to the availability of replacement height adjustment wheels which don't specify alternative thread pitches, I *guess* that's the only one in use. I encourage you to verify my finding before relying on it.

Comment: An additional piece of information: the stock adjustment wheels have 14 large sinusoidal bump crests around their circumference, so turning by one of these is an adjustment of exactly 0.05 mm.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Thanks, I added that to my answer in case someone else finds it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Just as Andrew, I did run a quick test to measure it: on my corner closest to <0,0,0>, a little stud is poking out. *Just* enough to screw on a threadcutter I know without any cutting happening:

[image]
[image]

Indeed, it is **M4x0.7**, aka coarse thread.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly tongue in cheek here, but if you can detect a 0.2 mm change, you may be able to determine visually the thread pitch, although it means de-tuning your bed for the experiment. Keeping close count is part of the experiment and you can reverse the count easily enough.

Make contact with the nozzle at the location of one screw. Count the turns in order to set the screw back to original location (or don't worry, re-tune later).

If the pitch is 0.5 mm, two complete turns would give you a millimeter, while the 0.7 mm pitch will give you 1.4 mm. Make it four turns and the difference is more apparent. That would present a 2.0 mm compared to 2.8 mm for the two types of threads.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the value is, but there are a few ways to find out. It is very hard to measure this with a caliper, but it can be done, mark the upper and bottom of e.g. 10 windings and measure this with a caliper. Alternatively measure how much the screw drops after 10 full turns.

There are special tools that give you the answer directly, they cost a few Euros/bucks but can be very handy; a thread gauge, just place the 0.5 mm and the 0.7 mm beside the screw and you will instantly see which is the correct one.

[image]

*I bought mine at a typical Chinese vendor site.*

Comment: An even more obvious way to measure this would be to get (or even print) some M4 0.7 and 0.5 nuts and see which (if either) successfully thread onto the exposed bottoms of the screws. With real metal ones you'd have to be careful not to damage the thread with the wrong one, but printed ones would be harmless. Probably would need a long interface to ensure that it doesn't "work" just by bending a couple threads.

Comment: Could also print a thread gauge like that, though it might be some work figuring out a way to do it with sufficient resolution.